# Thymeleaf Without Object Classes?

Tags: java, spring, oop, stored-procedures, thymeleaf

Is it possible to use Spring Boot and Thymeleaf without using object-oriented programming, And only handle the information in the database with stored procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Spring Framework is Java based and all supported languages use OOP paradigm.
I see you mix a lot of things together. Try to split them one by one, performing small steps. This will help you to move faster.